# Adding any pattern to match in regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex that works pretty well except in one particular situation;

```
$message = preg_replace("#(^(http(s)?://)(?!img.youtube.com/vi/)([-a-zA-Z?-??-?()0-9@:%_+.~\#?&;//=,]+(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.bmp|\.png)))#i", 
"<p><a href='/viewpost.php?messageid=$message_id'><img src='$1' width=100%></a>", $message);
```

This pattern does several things, 1) It exactly matches http or https, 2) it ignores any string that includes img.youtube.com/vi/ , and 3) it looks for popular image file types in the links.  It works the way it should only if their are no character before a sting (a sting like `http://exampleaddress/exampleimage.jpeg`).  If the string is in the middle of a paragraph, it fails.

I need to keep the ^(http(s)?://) as an exact match (removing ^ fixes my problem but causes a conflict with a subsequent regex rule.  So, it looks like the problem is that this exact match situation does not want any carriage returns, spaces, or anything to precede ^(http(s)?://) .  How can I make the regex work so that nothing before of after the string is relevant, but when you see exactly http or https to apply the rule?

Comment: Difficult to understand what the problem is without more detail on what fails.  But, a `\b` boundary may be what you need. `\bhttps?://` (note, no `()` needed around the `s` since the `?` applies to only the single preceding character...)

Comment: And standard warning applies: you should not be parsing HTML with a regular expression. Use a proper HTML/DOM parser instead, like DOMDocument.

Comment: Hi Michael - that totally worked.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: would you like me to add it as an answer below?

Comment: Absolutely, please do.  Thanks, Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, the `^` anchor requires the string to appear exactly at the beginning of the input string. You can achieve a similar restriction *anywhere* inside the input string with a `\b` word boundary. It matches a zero-length string at the start of a word - for example after but not including whitespace.

I'll note also that you do not need to surround the `s` in a `()` group, since the `?` will match only the single preceding character.

```
\bhttps?://...
```